# If mouse idle for particular time, move to 'container' page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing one task in javascript. I don't know how to solve this, in index page I am loading iframe to sub pages. If the mouse is idle for some time I am redirecting to index 'container'. It's not staying in sub page for given time, it's moving to 'index' page. I have attached my code. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please guide me.

```
var timeout = null;
    $(document).on('mousemove', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Mouse idle for 5 sec');
            $(".container").animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: 10 sec also its not waiting, its moving when working, i want to move only when ideal. is there some other idea to success this task

Comment: you're not catching the mousemove event of the containers over which you move your mouse. `$(document).on('mousemove'` will not catch all mouse movements anywhere on the page, especially iframe

Comment: Then how its possible kirill slatin ?? is there any way ??

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
   var timeout = null;
    $(document).on('mousemove','container', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Mouse idle for 5 sec');
            $(".container").animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        }, 10000);
    });
```

and change container to your container class or id (it will be best in case you have only one container). in mousemove event listner.

Comment: can your please provide jsfiddle of it ?